# could not find a javascript runtime in rails and unable to instal ' therubyracer' gem - on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:\sites\srhapp>rails generate controller home index
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `au
todetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/exe
cjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

This are the error messages i get. kindly help me out .

Answer (score 1):

Install `nodejs`. That may help here.

Follow [this](https://nodejs.org/download/).

Comment: Can you tell me how to install. ?? because i tried.. it doesnt work either 
even exejcs and therubytracer gems i installed .. still no use.

Comment: Opss. you had tried `nodejs`. So other thing may block you. keep trying. (y)

Comment: It just shows could not find any gem file.. while trying to install nodejs. 
Please suggest any other solution

Comment: you have to externally install `nodejs`. Not from the gem. Try this https://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: I have installed it now. So whats next ?? how will this effect the Javaruntime in rails ??

Comment: Rails using `ExecJS` and its supports `nodejs` at run time. https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#execjs

Comment: I saw that post earlier and thats how i installed execjs before, but still it shows the same error " runime unavailable"

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have Nodejs installed, see if any of these can help with the error you are getting (I was going to comment on jon snow's answer, but my suggestions became too long.):

1. Make sure you have `C:\Windows\System32` in your system's `PATH` variable.
2. Close and then restart your command console.
3. Type `node -v` into the console. Does Nodejs respond?
4. Change the `therubyracer` line in your Gemfile to `gem 'therubyracer', {:platforms => [:ruby]}`. As far as I know, `therubyracer` isn't for Windows, but declaring it this way lets it still be used in Heroku if you plan on using that later. Run `bundle install` after you make this change.

**Edit**

Do you necessarily need Puma in your Windows development environment? If you only need it for deployment on Heroku, the easiest way that I have found to get around its difficulty with Windows is by putting it into the production group along with any other gems Heroku requires.

*Gemfile*

```
...

group( :production ) do
    # Serves static assets in Heroku deployment.
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    # Web server for use with Heroku.
    gem 'puma'
    # Database used by Heroku.
    gem 'pg'
end

...
```

That way, you can simply exclude those gems when you `bundle install` in your local development environment.

```
$ bundle install --without production
```

If you really do need Puma on a Windows environment, you will have to install OpenSSL libraries and headers (so I have heard; I haven't tried it myself). The comment by luislavena on [this page](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/341) should help you in that case.

Comment: 1. Which console are you talking about?
2. where to type node -v ? as its not recognized anywhere.

Comment: The Git bash, or even just the Windows command prompt. Typing `node -v` should cause Nodejs to respond with the version that you have installed. Is it not?

Comment: Anyway, `node -v` is just a quick way to check if Windows is recognizing that Nodejs is installed. It is possible that restarting your computer could fix it, if you have not done so since installing Nodejs.

Comment: I'm installing heroku now..  and yes im getting the version for node -v

now this javaruntime has gone.. the next error message is similar to that 
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.
2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/pum
a-2.11.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing puma (2.11.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '2.11.2'` succeeds before bundling. .

Comment: I edited my answer to respond, since comments don't allow the same nice formatting options.